# Select the name of a certain value in a table (e.g. max)

Tags: r, names

I have a vector of numbers. Let's call it `mydata`:

```
str(mydata)
# num [1:236] 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
```

I can then count each value using `table`:

```
table(mydata)
# mydata
#  1    2    9  10 
# 20  200   14   2
```

Now, I want to select the value with the highest count (in this case, "2").

I can find the highest *count* (e.g. 200 in this case) by using the 
 max function: `max(table(mydata))`. But how to get the  *name* associated with the max count in the table, i.e. "2"?

Comment: if `tab` is your table `names(tab)[tab==max(tab)]`

Comment: `which.max` is also handy

Comment: Thanks to everybody that answered -- all the variations mentioned work!  This was exactly what I couldn't figure out.  I'm also not all that knowledgeable about stackflow, but if there is a "Solved" flag that needs to be set, I'd be happy to do it.

Comment: @WilliamOliver; you can click on the tick next to the answer that (best) solved your question [you can also click on the up arrow if you found either/both answer(s) useful]

Comment: Thanks.  I apparently do not have enough "reputation" to upclick.  I apologise to MrFlick (and user20650 and Mr Weissman) for only being able to choose one of the very helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `table` is very much like a list or a data frame, in that it has values and names (attributes) that are accessible through vector subsetting.

```
> mydata <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 200), rep(9, 14), rep(10, 2))
> tab <- table(mydata)
> tab
## mydata
##   1   2   9  10 
##  20 200  14   2
> names(tab)
## [1] "1"  "2"  "9"  "10" 
> c(val = names(tab)[tab == max(tab)], freq = max(tab))
##  val  freq 
##  "2" "200"
```

The following are equivalent

```
> tab[ names(tab)[tab == max(tab)] ]
##   2 
## 200
> tab["2"]
##   2
## 200
```

Other useful things to know about an object is described in its `attributes`

```
> attributes(tab)
$dim
[1] 4

$dimnames
$dimnames$mydata
[1] "1"  "2"  "9"  "10"

$class
[1] "table"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this

```
tab<-table(mydata)
names(tab)[which.max(tab)]
```

That will return "2" as a string. You can do as.numeric() if you want to get it back to a number. This one-liner is a bit more ugly and probably less efficient, but hey, it's one line.

```
sapply(list(table(mydata)), function(x) names(x[which.max(x)]))
```

or maybe

```
with(as.data.frame(table(data)), data[which.max(Freq)])
```

which will actually return a factor with a value of "2". If you want to make that numeric, you need to do `as.numeric(as.character(x))`. I was just trying to find ways to avoid having a table variable lying around if i really didn't need it. I wish there were an easier way to convert a table to a named vector.